# Get TextBox's value in compliance with selected RadioButton asp.net.mvc-4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

I need to create a view with a form where is a group of `RadioButton`s with `TextBox` for each of them. Then I want the `Model` to be filled with value in `TextBox` and value of selected `RadioButton`. I faced to the problem that I can't send value of **coresponding** to selected `RadioButton` `TextBox`.
It looks like this
[image]
There is my *Model*

```
public class CertainAnswersViewModel
{
    public int SelectedValue { get; set; }
    public string TextAnswer { get; set; }
    public bool IsInput { get; set; }
    public List<CertainAnswer> CertainAnswers { get; set; }
}
```

*View*

```
@using MY_BUKEP.Areas.Survey.Models;
@model CertainAnswersViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    foreach (var answer in Model.CertainAnswers)
    {
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedValue, answer.IdOption, new { id = "" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TextAnswer);
    <br />
    }
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

And there are two methods in *Controller*

```
[HttpGet]
public ViewResult Test()
{
    CertainAnswer ca1 = new CertainAnswer() { IdOption = 1 };
    CertainAnswer ca2 = new CertainAnswer() { IdOption = 2 };
    CertainAnswersViewModel cavm = new CertainAnswersViewModel();
    cavm.CertainAnswers = new List<CertainAnswer>();
    cavm.CertainAnswers.Add(ca1);
    cavm.CertainAnswers.Add(ca2);
    return View("TestView", cavm);
}

[HttpPost]
public void Test(CertainAnswersViewModel cavm)
{
    Answer a = new Answer();
    a.val = cavm.TextAnswer;
    a.idOption = cavm.SelectedValue;
}
```

Below is supposed result that I would like to achive
[image]
Would appreciate any help!

Comment: To clarify your question. `cavm.TextAnswer` is always empty for you?

Comment: No, if it has value in database it won't be. That's simple version. Full has own post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36694320/bind-radiobutton-to-textbox-asp-net-mvc-4) but I suppose it frightens people

Comment: Your loop works for the radio buttons, but not for the textbox because you creating duplicate textboxes for the same property (only the text in the first textbox will ever be bound. Its unclear what your trying to do.

Comment: Could you advice how should I send to controller within the Model selected value of RadioButton and corresponding value of TextBox?

Comment: @VitalyIsaenko, Your code makes no sense. You need to explain what it is your trying to do.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Seems that I really can't explain well, sorry. It is a survey, and people can write their own variants in the TextBoxes. Sometimes there can be more than one TextBox due to the fact that many aspects may exist. And I need to send only value of TextBox that's RadioButton is choosed.

Comment: Then you need just one textbox (generate it outside the loop) You can only choose one radiobutton so therefore there can be only one textbox. (but your radio buttons do not even have any labels so how does the user know if they have chosen `IdOption = 1` or `IdOption = 2`?)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I edited the question and attached a picture with supposed result but I think your variant is suitable! Thank you, you can post it as a question, I'll mark and vote)

Comment: @VitalyIsaenko you already try to do it with a normal for, instead of the foreach? also I think that SelectedValue  and TextAnswer  should be inside of CertainAnswer

Comment: @DanielGpeReyes yes, I tried it with normal _for_. The problem was that _for_ statement created `RadioButton`s with  different names like `[0]SelectedValue`, `[1]SelectedValue` and id made many separated `RadioButton`s instead of 1 group! These two fields were in `CertainAnswer` at first too but it made some troubles too. Maybe it is unclear because of choosen names of classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You current implementation is creating duplicate textboxes for the same property and when you submit the form only the value of the first textbox will be bound (if the user was to select the 3rd option and fill in the associated textbox, the value of `TextAnswer` will be `null` because the textbox associated with the 2nd option is empty. In addition your model(s) cannot generate the view you have shown in the second image because each `CertainAnswer` property also requires a value to indicate if an associated textbox is required (I'm assuming for some options, it may not be).

Your models would need to be (not I have change some class and property names to better describe what they represent)

```
public class PossibleAnswerVM
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool RequireAdditionalText { get; set; }
}
public class QuestionVM
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMesage = "Please select an option")]
    public int SelectedAnswer { get; set; }
    public string AdditionalText { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<PossibleAnswer> PossibleAnswers { get; set; }
}
```

and the code in your controller

```
QuestionVM model = new QuestionVM()
{
    ID = 1,
    Description = "If you could return to the past, what would you choose?",
    PossibleAnswers = new List<PossibleAnswer>()
    {
        new PossibleAnswer(){ ID = 1, Description = "Apply to another university" },
        new PossibleAnswer(){ ID = 2, Description = "Apply to the same ...", RequireAdditionalText = true }
    }
};
return View(model);
```

and the view

```
@model QuestionVM
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Question.ID)
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Question.Description)
    foreach(var option in Model.PossibleAnswers)
    {
        <label>
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedAnswer, option.ID, new { id = "" data_textrequired = option.RequireAdditionalText })
            <span>@option.Description</span>
        </label>
    }
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedAnswer)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AdditionalText)
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Note that a `data-textrequired` has been added so that you could use javascript to show/hide the textbox based on the selected option. You could also use javascript to position the textbox adjacent the selected option if necessary

Comment: Yes, it's fine for me, thanks! Actually, something in your answer exist in my view and model, but it wasn't included because it would hide my question. But I also found some intresting details and will implement them undoubtedly.